# jquery dialog not opened after a page load using load function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am loading a page using load function the dialog is not open but when i refresh a page the dialog is worked. The alert is working using load(). Any suggestions?

```
jQuery( "#edit-address-map" ).live('click', function(){
            alert('in');
            jQuery( "#edit-address-map-div" ).dialog({ 
                modal: true,
                height:370,
                width:350,
                resizable: true,
                draggable: false,
                dialogClass: "flora",
                close: function(ev, ui) { jQuery(this).dialog('destroy'); }

             });    

        });
```

Comment: Is this function inside a [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function?

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: This is inside a ready function and there is no error in console.If i put like the below then "this._mouseInit is not a function" will occur

Comment: There must be something else interfering with this then. Because it works for me in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZPdpV/1/

Comment: Yes It's working fine in jsfiddle but the problem is i loaded the page using load() at the time dialog is not open. When i refresh the page the dialog is open

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to open the `edit-address-map-div` dialog when you click on the `edit-address-map` element. Right?

```
$(function() {

    jQuery( "#edit-address-map" ).live('click', function(){
        alert('in'); 
        $('#edit-address-map-div').dialog("open"); // raise the open event on click
    });

    // wire up the dialog properties when the DOM loads
    jQuery( "#edit-address-map-div" ).dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, // so it won't open when the page loads
        modal: true,
        height:370,
        width:350,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: false,
        dialogClass: "flora",
        close: function(ev, ui) { jQuery(this).dialog('destroy'); }
    });   
});
```